# JNI parameters are local or global references

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I've read several references about local and global references in JNI. But I couldn't find a definite answer whether Java object which is passed as parameter to the JNI function is local or global reference. I supposed that it should be global, however there is one problem:

First I get the Java-object pointer and save it. Then the native callback function calls method of that object. The callback function is called from a separate thread. The thread was created using AttachCurrentThread(), so JVM knows about it. JNIEnv* variable is also valid and the object was not garbage callected, however I get warning and then crash.

> JNI WARNING: 0x4108edb8 is not a valid JNI reference in
>   Lcom/my/company/MyClass;.load:(Ljava/lang/String;)V (GetObjectClass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you can get a global ref if the function is not called from Java code (I sometimes call my JNI methods directly from other JNI methods without asking the JVM to do it) but you should always assume them to be local and treat them like that. If you want to store them for later use, you should create a new gobal reference. 
In fact, even if you could get a global ref, there would be no difference in how you should treat them. You don't have to delete them in any case and even if you do happen to get a global reference (I think the way described above is the only way), storing it without first making a new reference of it would be wrong. If whoever gave it to you deletes the ref it will turn invalid.

**Edit:** The above is an edited version which I hope will satisfy @EJP more. Same message, just clearer. And he does have a point that for almost all cases, the JNI spec is all that matters even if it makes no difference in this case :-)

Comment: Think you're right, cause I've just tried the NewGlobalRef and there was no crash. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to call DeleteGlobalRef() when you're done with it or you will have a memory leak of the object and everything referenced by it.

Comment: Yep. I think that I should better use the NewWeakGlobalRef() instead, cause with NewGlobalRef() that object won't be freed at all.

Comment: One more question please. Is finalize() Java method is a valid place to clean all native resources ?

Comment: They serve different purposes... If you do NewGlobalRef() you will have to call DeleteGlobalRef() (and then it will be up for gc). With NewWeakGlobalRef your jobject risk being gone the when you need it. If that is ok or not depends very much on your usecase. Remember to check if it is valid before you use it or whatever you call is likely to crash, in the best case with an exception, in worst case hard.

Comment: finalize() is hardly ever a good place to cleanup things in java if it can be avoided. You're not even guaranteed to get there and the existence of a finalizer itself will make the work of the gc a lot harder (for different reasons which comments aren't really the place to discuss).

Comment: It's a local reference, see my answer.

Comment: @EJP Yes, most likely. However, as with any call, you really don't know what the caller put there (I sometimes call my JNI functions directly from other JNI functions) and the JVM will not be able replace the jobject I pass with other local references to them (at least not the JVMs I am using) which is why I wrote "They probably can be global but you should assume them to be local".

Comment: There is no 'most likely' about it. It is a *fact*, documented in the JNI Specification I cited. You do 'really know what the caller put there', *except* in your strange case of calling your own JNI methods from others. And no JVM would be able to do the substitution you mention as the JVM isn't in that path of execution. All the more reason you shouldn't do it. If you do it, arguably you should observe the rule I quoted too and pass local not global references, like the JVM, so this issue doesn't arise.

Comment: I know it is the spec (and I know the spec, quite well actually). But surely you can agree that as long as there is something you can call "a strange case" which is an exception there is a "most likely" situation covering the rest? It is not that strange to do it, it is in fact quite likely if you have a large chunk of performance demanding JNI code and you don't want to take a roundtrip over the JVM just to call one of your methods from another to avoid code duplication. But it really doesn't matter for anyone as long as you adhere to the spec and consider all arguments as local (as I wrote).

Comment: @Fredrik You described what I wrote as 'most likely'. It is a fact. There are other situations in which it may not be a fact, which you hadn't introduced when I commented. The OP is asking specifically about 'Java objects which [are] passed as parameter to the JNI function', not about your corner case.

Comment: @EJP If it is a big problem for you I can edit the answer slightly but I really don't understand your obsession about it. It is good that you also know the spec but what are you trying to prove? Anyone who have read just the first comments on this answer will understand that we agree with the spec on how it works when the call is coming from the JVM and that it really doesn't matter at all for the callee as not even a global reference passed in from the outside would be safe to store and that there is no difference in how a global and local reference passed as arguments needs to be handled.

Answer (score 5):

1. It's a local reference. ["Objects are passed to native methods as local references"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp1242)
2. JNIEnv* pointers are not valid across JNI method call boundaries let alone thread boundaries.
3. In your circumstance you must convert the local reference to a global reference for use by the callback method.